# Give priority to some fields when selecting

Tags: mysql, sql

So let's say i have these fields

```
+----------+-------+---------+
| username | email | online  |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

Now i would like to run this query,

`SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 20`, pretty simple, but i would like to select first those fields which have `online` field with value `1` and then select all of the rest fields

So if i have these records:

```
user1,   email@email, 0
user2,   email@email, 1
user3,   email@email, 0
user4,   email@email, 1
```

After selecting i should get

```
user2,   email@email, 1
user4,   email@email, 1
user1,   email@email, 0
user3,   email@email, 0
```

I know i could do this job with php, but it would be extra work if mysql can do this for me.

Comment: You did not look in the documentation, did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY online DESC,username LIMIT 20;
```

You may want to add this index as well

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX online_username_ndx (online,username);
```

If there are other values for online besides 0 and 1, then do this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY IF(online=1,0,1),username LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 5):

Pretty simple, just order by it the 'online' column in descending order.

```
select * from users order by online DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY online DESC, username LIMIT 20`

Answer (score 2):

why cant you just add an ORDER BY clause?

```
order by online DESC LIMIT 20
```